# Check Google+ group membership with REST API

Tags: rest, google-plus

I would like to restrict access to a certain webpage to members of a specific (invite-only) Google Plus group. This is not on a Google Apps domain, I know the API there is different.

I don't see any HTTPS-based API in Google's list that can be used, the one for public G+ profiles only shows profile info and activity flow. I may be overlooking something, or there might be a language binding that can be used from a web server.

Note that the purpose isn't to get a list of user IDs for the group (I have the necessary access to get that by other means), nor the list of groups that a user belongs to (a privacy infringement)-- I just want a dynamic yes/no answer whether the user belongs to the group right now.

Alternatively, is there a way to get/refresh the list of members of a group without scraping a web page?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here seams more like a statement.  Is it possible to get a list of members of a google plus group / community though any API?  No.

Comment: Well, the question is, am I overlooking something? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Your not.  You cant find out who is a member of a group with any api currently in existence

Comment: Bummer. I built a scraper.